# title&&close button not show

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, osx-yosemite

I try to show/hide the title bar in a cocoa app. I use following code :

```
    if ([window styleMask]==NSResizableWindowMask) {
        [window setStyleMask:NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask|NSTitledWindowMask];
    }else{
        [window setStyleMask:NSResizableWindowMask];
    }
```

It works well before 10.10 but fails in 10.10. In 10.10, when the title bar is shown, the title, close/minimize/resize buttons are unshown. Only user resizes the window, those things will be shown.
I guess that something needs to be 'Flush' and hence I also try to add:

```
    [window update];
    [window display];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setWindowsNeedUpdate:YES];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] updateWindows];
```

But all is failed.
Could anyone give any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting issue. Can you file a bug report with Apple?

In the meantime, here is a hack that seems to fix the issue:

```
if ([window styleMask] == NSResizableWindowMask) {
    NSDisableScreenUpdates();

    [window setStyleMask:(NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask
                           |NSResizableWindowMask|NSTitledWindowMask)];

    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    frame.size.width += 1;
    [window setFrame:frame display:NO];
    frame.size.width -= 1;
    [window setFrame:frame display:YES];

    NSEnableScreenUpdates();
} else {
    [window setStyleMask:NSResizableWindowMask];
}
```

(In addition, it seems that you will have to manually restore the title with `setTitle:`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if ([window styleMask]==NSResizableWindowMask)
    {
        [window setStyleMask:NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask|NSTitledWindowMask];
    }
    else
    {
        [window setStyleMask:NSResizableWindowMask];
    }
});
```

it works in my case.